# ASP.NET MVC project filterattribute to a normal function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, filterattribute

I have an asp.net mvc project which is divided into projectlayers: 
Test has the controller which calls the taskproject. In task a function calls the database and returns the data.
TestProject:

```
Homecontroller()
{
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Person> pers = PersonTask.getPersons();
         return View(pers);
    }
 }
```

TaskProject:

```
   public static List<Person> getPersons()
    {
        using (var context = new FilterTestEntities())
        {
            return context.People.OrderBy(p => p.PersonID).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I want to have a filter on the data i return to the controller. I know there is a FilterAttribute, but as far as I know this is only possible on an action function. Is it possible to put a filterAttribute on my getPersons() function. Like:

```
[PersonFilter]      
public static List<Person> getPersons()
```

Thanks.

Comment: @dove are you implying, that i am wrong?

Comment: @tereško no, don't take it the wrong way. you're right, just seen the identical comment a couple of times (which is also fine).  thinking about it now though doesn't the tagging give the context of which Mvc they're talking about?

Comment: @dove , in that case you would need to look at the revision history `=P` because this is not how it was originally tagged. And yes, I have few "predefined" comments.

Comment: @tereško fair point.  i'll keep an eye out for some of the others and see if i can collect some more ;)

Comment: @tereško haha I will not make the same mistake;)